# c# using arrays as a map

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm relatively new to C# and I'm creating a basic old-school dungeon questing game to help me get to grips with visual studio and windows forms.

I would like to use an array of objects as a map which I can then move between (please let me know if there's a better way). *(edit for clarity)* So if I started in currentroom = maparray[0,1], pressing left would change it to currentroom = maparray[0,0]

Here is my array code:

```
        public object area_init()
    {Area hall = new Area("Hall", "big hall", "null", false, 1, 2, false);
        Area room = new Area("Room", "room", "null", false, 1, 2, false);

        Area[,] maparray = { { hall, room, hall }, 
            { hall,hall,room},
            { hall,room,room}
        };
object[,] maparray = new object[3,3];
```

I was then wanting to refer to the room I was currently in like so (I know this is incorrect):

```
txtbox_ticker.AppendText("You are in a " + maparray[0,1]);
```

And then update a 'currentroom' variable to say which room I'm in. Could anyone tell me the best way to do this, and where I'm going wrong?

Comment: A [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) would work well here.  `Dictionary<string,Area> myDungeon`.

Comment: Would a Dictionary wouldn't allow me to move around in a 2D space? 
My reason behind using an array is that rows and columns sort of work out  as a basic map.

If your currentroom was maparray[0,1], pressing left would move you to maparray[0,0] and so on.

Comment: each area could have `string left = "name of room left"` as a property.  Then you can get the new area by calling `myDungeon[currentArea.left]`.  What you really need is more of a connected graph structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Areas could be considered nodes in a connected graph.  The edges are defined by what nodes a particular node is connected to.

You could define your area class something like this.

```
public class Area
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Left {get;set;}
    public string Right {get;set;}
    public string Up {get;set;}
    public string Down {get;set;}

    // if you really need an x-y location put it here.
}
```

Then have a dictionary in the background to access the relevant information.  Dictionaries are great because you can use the name of a room to access its properties rather than an index.

```
Dictionary<string,Area> MyDungeon = new Dictionary<string,Area>();

// define two areas that are linked.

Area hall = new Area();
hall.Name = "hall"
hall.Left = "room"; // go left from here to get to the room

Area room = new Area();
room.Name = "room";
room.Right = "hall"; // go right to get to the hall

MyDungeon.Add(hall.Name,hall);
MyDungeon.Add(room.Name,room);
```

Let's start the user off in the hall.

```
Area CurrentArea = MyDungeon["hall"];
```

Now say the user presses the left arrow key and you need to handle it.  You could do something like the following.

```
private void Move_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Left)
      {
          CurrentArea = MyDungeon[CurrentArea.Left];
          txtbox_ticker.AppendText("You are now in " + CurrentArea.Name);
      }

    else if(e.Key == Key.Right)
      {
          CurrentArea = MyDungeon[CurrentArea.Right];
          txtbox_ticker.AppendText("You are now in " + CurrentArea.Name);
      }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much Felix - you've made a truly amateur developer very happy.

Comment: my pleasure, glad it helped.